# Returning a string from a Rust function to be called with FFI

Tags: lua, rust, ffi, luajit

I want to have an interpreted language (specifically LuaJIT) call a Rust function that returns a string.

What I have crashes before I even dereference the pointer.

I read that Rust strings are not null-terminated, so I am using the `to_c_str()` function to make a string that is, but I figure lifetimes are somehow throwing a wrench in the whole thing since I am still somewhat foggy about them.

Rust code:

```rust
#![crate_type = "dylib"]

extern crate libc;

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn hello_world() -> std::c_str::CString {
    "Hello World".to_c_str()
}
```

Lua code:

```lua
local ffi = require("ffi")
ffi.cdef[[
char *hello_world();
]]

local hello_world = ffi.load("hello_world")
local hw = hello_world.hello_world()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A  `CString` isn't only a pointer; [it's a pointer plus a boolean](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/f168c12c5629afd45c9b3ed250350bf830b99642/src/librustrt/c_str.rs#L92-L95) that indicates if the `CString` owns the C string. Because of this, the declaration in your Lua code doesn't match the definition in your Rust code.

Return a `*const c_char` or a `*mut c_char` by using the [`unwrap`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/c_str/struct.CString.html#method.unwrap) method on `CString`. If your function returns a dynamically allocated string, you also need to provide a function to free the string that the Lua code needs to call manually, otherwise it will cause a memory leak.

Answer (score 3):

[Francis Gagné's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26570718/155423) is correct. Here's the complete working solution.

Rust code:

```rust
#![crate_type = "dylib"]

extern crate libc;

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn hello_world() -> *const libc::c_char {
    unsafe { "Hello World".to_c_str().unwrap() }
}
```

Lua code:

```lua
local ffi = require("ffi")
ffi.cdef[[
char *hello_world();
]]

local hello_world = ffi.load("hello_world")
local hw = ffi.string(hello_world.hello_world())
```